# Deligne-Simpson problem for classical groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Additive Deligne-Simpson problem was partially prooved by Kostov. Also there is Crawley-Boevey's approach to the question. The problem is about existence of a solution of the equation
$$
A_1 +...+A_n = 0,
$$
where $A_i \in \mathcal{O}_i$, and $\mathcal{O}_i$ is a fixed coadjoint orbit in $\mathfrak{gl}_r$. How the land lies in the case of other classical groups such as orthogonal or symplectic?